# How to get transit route with taxi from Google Directions API?

Tags: python, android, google-maps, google-directions-api

Google Maps for Android (but not in the Web version) can build a route that contains different kinds of transport like "public transport + taxi" in [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-maps-mixed-route-directions-ridesharing-biking/) topic.
[image: google maps]

How can I get the route with a taxi from Google Directions (REST) API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the multiple modes of transportation feature on [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com) is not yet available from the Google Maps Platform - [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start).

But, we do have an existing feature request for this in our Google Issue Tracker. To express your interest and to subscribe you to its latest updates, I suggest that you star this entry: https://issuetracker.google.com/136932316